# SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL quoted table name for User, with Flask-Login

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-login

Consider the following declarative User model in SQLAlchemy:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    email = Column(String(1024), unique=True)
    points = Column(Integer, default=0)
    achievements = relationship('Achievement', 
    secondary=achievement_association_table,
    backref='users')
    reviews = relationship('Review', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    moderated = Column(Boolean, default=True)
```

When I do a `SELECT * FROM user`, I noticed that the query was not returning all of my columns, and showed only the "current_user" column which I can only surmise is a result of using Flask-Login.

Making the query `User.query.all()` resulted in the following SQL:

```
SELECT "user".created AS user_created, "user".modified AS user_modified, "user".id AS user_id, "user".username AS user_username, "user".email AS user_email, "user".points AS user_points, "user".moderated AS user_moderated
```

Can anyone help me understand why this table was created double quoted? None of my other (similarly defined) declarative models exhibit this behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a reserved words and thus needs to be quoted.

More details about quoted identifiers are in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS